# Javascript filter data based on multiple fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have multiple input fields where the user can enter data and based on that input, the list has to be filtered.

In the below code there is users array and I tried to filter 2 field data then join both arrays result and then I remove duplicate data but this is not working correctly.

> My code filter array for one field but I am unable to filter for more than one.

```
const users = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Bravo",
        "email": "John@bravo.com",
        "specialty": "Surgeon",
        "location": "Los Angeles",
        "about": "Blablabla" 
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "firstname": "Phil",
        "lastname": "Kiwil",
        "email": "phil@kiwil.com",
        "specialty": "Business & Entrepreneurship",
        "location": "Location",
        "about": "Something"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Doe",
        "email": "john@doe.com",        
        "specialty": "Surgeon",
        "location": "NY",
        "about": "Some text lorem ipsum"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "firstname": "Jimi",
        "lastname": "Henix",
        "email": "jimi@henix.om",
        "specialty": "Expert",
        "location": "Woodstock",
        "about": "Something goes here",
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "firstname": "Janis",
        "lastname": "Jopn",
        "email": "janis@jopn.com",
        "specialty": "Surgeon",
        "location": "Los Angeles",
        "about": "Something something description text",
    }
]
```

**My Code**

```
this.state = {
            users:[],
            filter:[],
            location:"",
            specialty:""
        }
const {location,specialty,users} = this.state;
        var trimedLocation = location.trim(); 
        var trimedSpecialty = specialty.trim(); 
        const filter = users.filter(user =>{
            if(location == "" || specialty == ""){
                return (user.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(trimedLocation.toLowerCase()) !== -1) &&
                (user.specialty.toLowerCase().indexOf(trimedSpecialty.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
            } else {
                return (user.location.toLowerCase().indexOf(trimedLocation.toLowerCase()) !== -1) ||
                (user.specialty.toLowerCase().indexOf(trimedSpecialty.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
            }
        });
        this.setState({filter});
```

Comment: I edit the post with working code.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you need to filter only users or even location at the same time. If you mean to filter users with multiple conditions you could try this approach.

```
const userFiltered = users.filter(user =>{
 return user.location.toLowerCase().includes(trimedLocation.toLowerCase() &&
        user.specialty.toLowerCase().includes(trimedSpecialty.toLowerCase()) ;
});
```

This is and `AND` condition. You can change it to be an `OR` if you want replacing `&&` with `||`.

Update:
here is a working example that handle partial string and `null` or `undefined` values.
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-rosalind-8ztzq?file=/src/App.tsx:1386-1387

Comment: I want to filter users e.g: If I add (surgeon)speciality of user and (Los angeles)location of user the list should show all the users who have speciality surgeon and Were in Los Angeles. And if I give only speciality the result should show all the users with that specialty. I already used this code check this exercise app [link](https://expo.dev/artifacts/748124b5-260c-44b4-a31f-cee2c5908f1f)

Comment: ok. so use the AND version of the above code.

Comment: **||** is not working correctly. When I enter the location(los angeles) and leave speciality empty it shows me all data and vice versa. It should show me only data with location (los ageles). When I add location and speciality both whether it is right or wrong it shows me the correct result according to given input.

Comment: You should handle `null|undefined` values in the trimmed variables and add them to the condition only when they have a value.

Comment: Update the response with a simple example.